# How to get CatBoost model's coefficients?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, catboost

I need to get the parameters to use the model in another program.

I tried  `cat_model.coef_`, `cat_model.intercept_` or what I think. is that possible to catch the params ?

I totally solved this problem, what i was tryna do is named 'saving model'.

```
 cat_model.save_model('cat_model.cbm')
```

Answer (score 1):

Attributes .coef_ and .intercept_ only exist in sklearn applications of linear regression and logistic regression and will give you the slopes and the intercept (if fitted). You can use .feature_importances_  instead.

Comment: I solved my little problem, just wanted to use a model permanently. CatBoost already has an option for my wish. Teşekkür ederim yine de..

Answer (score 0):

For catboost, your model has something called feature importances, given that it's a gradient boosting tree model what you get back is how heavy certain features are in splitting the tree up.

```
cat_model.feature_importances_
```

will tell you that. Though you should do more research into how the model works and what it will give you back because interpreting these features can be somewhat deceptive.

Comment: all what I want to do is fix my model, i didn't find any `random_state` parameters. I try to do that when i open my project and get some predict, I wanna take always the same predictions. How ? is that possible ?

Comment: That isn't what the original question was. But what do you think is wrong with your model?

Comment: actually questions are the same, i want to know the coefficients because i want to use the model somewhere else. Like a CART model's if structure, or coefficients of a stats model from sklearn